# Sturm-Louiville Problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Sturm-Louiville problem

$y''+ \lambda y=0 , y'(0)=0, y(2) =0$

I need to find the eigenvalues, $\lambda_n$ and I thought I'd found it to be $\frac{2n\pi-\pi}{4}$ but apparently this is wrong.

With the case $\lambda>0$, I get the general solution $y(x)=Acos(\mu x)+Bsin(\mu x)$ and using the conditions given

$y'(0)=0 , -A\mu sin(\mu 0)+B\mu cos(\mu 0)=B\mu=0,$ therefore $B=0$

and

$y(2)=0, A cos(2\mu)=0,$ therefore $\mu =\frac{2n\pi-\pi}{4}$

What have I done wrong, any insight would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Can you share how you got those eigenvalues? Perhaps we can find the mistake.

Comment: If you found eigenvalues, then you probably found eigenfunctions at the same time. With that information, you can simply check to see if your eigenvalue/eigenfunction pairs work. If not, you can remove the word "apparently" from your question. :)

Comment: Is here $\lambda>0$?

Answer (score 0):

Assume $\lambda>0$. Let $y=re^{ikx}$ be the fundamental solution to your ODE where $k$ and $r$ are constants to be determined. Plug it into ODE, we have:
$$
-rk^2e^{ikx}+\lambda re^{ikx}=0
$$
which gives $k=\pm\sqrt{\lambda}$. That means the general solution of your ODE is $y=r(e^{i\sqrt{\lambda}x}+e^{-i\sqrt{\lambda}x})=2r\cos(\sqrt{\lambda }x)$

Obviously, the solution satisfy $y'(0)=0$. Then $y(2)=0$ gives
$$
2r\cos(2\sqrt{\lambda})=0\\
\lambda_n=(\dfrac{\pi}{4}+\dfrac{n\pi}{2})^2 \qquad n\in N^+
$$
Hope this is helpful.

Comment: How do I calculate $l$ in the solution

Comment: I edited the answer. It denote the arbitrary integer.

Comment: That makes sense, but it's still appearing as wrong when I enter it

Comment: What method do you take to check it?

Comment: I just enter it online and it tells me whether it's correct. It's possible the program is wrong but unlikely. Although your answer makes sense so I don't know.